# Add a top level empty directory to a zip file on Windows

Tags: windows, zip

When creating a zip file with Windows, it gives an error message if adding an empty folder and excludes it. It is no problem if you add a directory containing a child directory that is empty, but if you want to add an empty folder as a top-level folder then how can this be done?

> The specified directory is empty, so Compressed (zipped) Folders cannot add it to the archive.
> [image: Image showing this error message.]

> Windows was unable to add one or more empty directories to the Compressed (zipped) Folder.
> [image: Image showing this warning message.]

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell with .NET 4.5 or later, you can manually create an empty directory in a new or existing zip file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395011/1507941

1. Open a PowerShell prompt.
2. Enter the following commands, substituting the filenames as appropriate:

```sh
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.IO.Compression'
Add-Type -Assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'

# Must be used for relative file locations with .NET functions instead of Set-Location:
[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory('.\Desktop')

# Replace "Update" with "Create" if creating a new zip file
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open('archive.zip', [System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode]::Update)

# Get folder to be created
$existingFile = Get-Item 'Empty Folder'

# Create directory copying its attributes
$entry = $zip.CreateEntry($existingFile.Name + '/')

# Set modified date manually to match empty folder you wanted to add
$entry.LastWriteTime = $existingFile.LastWriteTime

# Closes file and allows it to be opened elsewhere
$zip.Dispose()
```

Feel free to review this library's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression